# MySQL - GEOMETRY

Tags: mysql, sql, spatial-query

I have two tables. One with points and another is with polygons. How could I find which point inside of which polygon?

Comment: Not enough information for people to answer this question.  Please elaborate.

Comment: @AllenKing which information should I add?

Comment: @AllenKing two table with polygons and points respectively. I need to find which point is inside of which polygon

Comment: @AllenKing I stuck with sql query

Comment: @AllenKing please tell me how could I improve my question

Comment: Please share sample data from both of your tables.

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur the data has Polygon and Point data types. How is possible to share it?

Comment: contains and st_contains functions will do the job.

Comment: @Shadow I wrote the following query but it did not work **SELECT messagespoints.coordinates FROM messagespoints WHERE ST_CONTAINS(messagespoints.coordinates, (SELECT geofencespolygon.coordinates FROM geofencespolygon));**

Comment: In st_contains() first parameter will be polygon and the second parameter will be point. Answered with db-fiddle example. Thanks for asking the question.

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur I thought if I am looking for which point is inside of which polygon the point should be the first. And also when I ran the query MySQL showed me error that the subquery has more than one rows and it didn't say anything about parameters

Comment: Thanks for such nice question. Best wishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just misplaced the parameters in `ST_CONTAINS()`, first parameter will be polygon and second one will be point, since ST_CONTAINS(g1,g2) will return 1 if g1 completely contains g2 or will return 0.

```
SELECT messagespoints.coordinates FROM messagespoints 
WHERE T_CONTAINS( (SELECT geofencespolygon.coordinates 
FROM geofencespolygon),messagespoints.coordinates)
```

You can also join both tables using `ST_Contains()` in `on clause` as shown below:

```
SELECT messagespoints.coordinates 
FROM geofencespolygon
inner join messagespoints 
on ST_CONTAINS(geofencespolygon.coordinates,messagespoints.coordinates)
```

DB-Fiddle:

```
 Schema and insert statements:

 create table testPoly(polID int, pol polygon);

 create table testPoint(pntID int, pnt point);
 insert into testPoint values(1,ST_GeomFromText('POINT(2 1)')); 
 insert into testPoint values(2,ST_GeomFromText('POINT(5 3)')); 
 insert into testPoint values(3,ST_GeomFromText('POINT(5 10)')); 

 INSERT INTO testPoly VALUES (1,ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((0 0, 8 0, 4 4, 0 0))'));
```

Query:

```
 select polID,pntID
 FROM testPoly 
 inner join testPoint
 on ST_Contains(pol, pnt)
```

Output:

| polID | pntID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0b11ee80778cbd07f63e093268056c8a)*